# How to merge for loop output dataframes into one with python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as following:

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns=list('A'))
dfb = pd.DataFrame(['AC', 'BC', 'CC'], columns=list('B'))
```

And my output is to generate a new dataframe with column B in dfb and another column of distance(e.g. Hamming distance from AC to AA is 1) between every element from B to A, like this:

```
   B    disB  disB disB
0  AC    1    2    1
1  BC    2    1    1
2  CC    2    2    0
```

The codes I have tried like this (courtesy of other posts):

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns=list('A'))
dfb = pd.DataFrame(['AC', 'BC', 'CC'], columns=list('B'))

df_summary = dfb.copy()

for seq1 in dfa.A:
    df__ = []
    for seq2 in dfb.B:
        hd = sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(seq1, seq2))
        df__.append(hd)

    df_summary['dis_{}'.format(column)] = pd.DataFrame({'dis_' + column: df__}).values
    print(df_summary)
```

The result will give me 3 outputs:

```
    B  dis_B
0  AC      1
1  BC      2
2  CC      2
    B  dis_B
0  AC      2
1  BC      1
2  CC      2
    B  dis_B
0  AC      1
1  BC      1
2  CC      0
```

but I need to combine them into one, like:

```
   B    disB  disB disB
0  AC    1    2    1
1  BC    2    1    1
2  CC    2    2    0
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized (read "much faster") solution:

```
a = np.array(dfa['A'].str.split('').str[1:-1].tolist())
b = np.array(dfb['B'].str.split('').str[1:-1].tolist())

dfb[['disB_1', 'disB_2', 'disB_3']] = (a != b[:, None]).sum(axis=2)
```

Output:

```
>>> dfb
    B  disB_1  disB_2  disB_3
0  AC       1       2       1
1  BC       2       1       1
2  CC       2       2       0
```

Comment: Really fast! One more question I have is if I have 1000 columns of disB_1, disB_2,..., disB_1000, how do I name it automatically?

Comment: @Makunata This should do it: `dfb = pd.concat([dfb, pd.DataFrame((a != b[:, None]).sum(axis=2)).add_prefix('disB_')], axis=1)`

Comment: You can also simply label the columns using the strings that are used to calculate the Hamming distances in the columns, which may be a more natural naming convention, and almost certainly more intuitive since then the columns will be self-documenting, just like the rows which have as index the strings from 'B'.

Comment: Naming is not essential here. I created them to explain the meaning of each element.

Comment: The suggestion in my comment was meant to respond to the question in your comment and not particular to the answer by @richardec.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that gives a result in a slightly different form than the question frames things, but uses the values of 'A' and 'B' as the `index` and `columns` of the dataframe result, which may be more descriptive of the ultimate result:

```py
import pandas as pd

lists = {'A' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], 'B' : ['AC', 'BC', 'CC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[sum(c != d for c, d in zip(lists['B'][i], lists['A'][j])) for j in range(len(lists['A']))] for i in range(len(lists['B']))], index=lists['B'], columns=lists['A'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    AA  BB  CC
AC   1   2   1
BC   2   1   1
CC   2   2   0
```

Here is a performance comparison between the above approach creating a general matrix and a solution using `numpy` shown in another answer which uses hardcoded column names:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lists = {'A' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], 'B' : ['AC', 'BC', 'CC']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[sum(c != d for c, d in zip(lists['B'][i], lists['A'][j])) for j in range(len(lists['A']))] for i in range(len(lists['B']))], index=lists['B'], columns=lists['A'])
print(df)


dfa = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns=list('A'))
dfb = pd.DataFrame(['AC', 'BC', 'CC'], columns=list('B'))

def foo(dfa, dfb):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[sum(c != d for c, d in zip(dfb['B'][i], dfa['A'][j])) for j in range(len(dfa['A']))] for i in range(len(dfb['B']))], index=dfb['B'], columns=dfa['A'])
    return df
    


def bar(dfa, dfb):
    a = np.array(dfa['A'].str.split('').str[1:-1].tolist())
    b = np.array(dfb['B'].str.split('').str[1:-1].tolist())
    dfb[['disB_1', 'disB_2', 'disB_3']] = (a != b[:, None]).sum(axis=2)
    return dfb

import timeit

print("\nGeneral matrix approach:")
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: foo(dfa, dfb), number = 100)
print(f"timeit: {t}")

print("\nHarcoded columns approach:")
t = timeit.timeit(lambda: bar(dfa, dfb), number = 100)
print(f"timeit: {t}")
```

Output and performance via `timeit`:

```
    AA  BB  CC
AC   1   2   1
BC   2   1   1
CC   2   2   0

General matrix approach:
timeit: 0.023536499997135252

Harcoded columns approach:
timeit: 0.03922149998834357
```

This seems to show that the `numpy` approach takes about 1.5-2x as long as the general matrix approach in this answer.

Comment: Actually, I have a huge file of dfb. I was wondering if there is an automatical naming method for your initial defined 'lists' without specifying the names.

Comment: @Makunata Can you please clarify a bit. It seems like you have multiple dfb "lists" in a file. Is there also an actual dfa "list" somewhere, and is there just one of these? I was picturing one axis of your results being a single dfb list and the other axis being a single dfa list - is this correct, or is the shape of your data different?